# Laravel Form Model Binding with Relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to bind a form with a model that has relationships? For example I have a Order model that has a one to many with a Details model. That would save a lot of time with

```
@foreach($order->details as $detail)
{{ Form::text('product_name', Input::old('product_name') ? Input::old('product_name') : detail->product_name)
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 10):

For a `one-to-one` relation it's possible to use something like this:

```
Form::text('detail[product_name]')
```

In this case `$order->detail->product_name` will be populated in the given text box if an instance of `Order` model is bound to the `from` using `Form::model($order)` with the related model `Detail` but it may not possible for `one-to-many` because simply there will be a collection and you need a loop.

Comment: No way to do it for a collection, so like you said this works only for `hasOne` or `belongsTo`.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know.

Comment: It makes sense as well :-)

Comment: Could I call the collection as such and apply `->lists`?

Comment: Forgive me sir, I was drifting.

Answer (score 3):

To complete the answer of @WereWolf..

- Make an array of product_name `detail_names`
- Input class allow you to access nested array by dot notation, eg: `orders.1.product_name`
- Don't forget the second argument of `Input::old()` or `Input::get()`
  is the default value, so you can specify the DB value and avoid conditional test..

.

```
Form::text('detail_names['.$detail->id.']', Input::old('detail_names.'.$detail->id, $detail->product_name))
```

In your controller, something like that:

```
foreach(Input:get('detail_names') as $id => $product_name)
{
    //...
}
```

Hope this will help you to save a bit of time.